# force images to use another domain ( located in same server )

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my problem:

Let's say I got two identical pages located in the same server.

1st one has a domain named www.mydomain1.com and
2nd one has a domain named www.mydomain2.com

I'm displaying images on both sites ( they are identical ) but to limit the percentage of screwing something up I want to use the same domain to display images on both sites.

Links are identical, but I just need to use www.mydomain1.com/images/... to display the image while on www.mydomain2.com

I have searched and searched but I havent found anything useful to help me on my journey.

BR's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should do what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://mydomain1.com/images/$1 [L]
```